# Method 'real_escape_string' not found, how to fix?

Tags: php

I have a php code file like this:

```
require_once 'login.php';
$conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);
...
function get_post($conn, $var){
    return $conn -> real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
}
```

The IDE tells me that the method 'real_escape_string' not found. Can anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: real_escape_string to mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: Use parameterized queries.

Comment: I tried mysqli_real_escape_string, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometime autoloading of default PHP function doesn't work in IDE. Please use directly or try others methods like `mysqli_real_escape_string` or escape_string. Also let me know which IDE are you using.

Comment: I used phpStorm. Although the IDE says that the method is not found, the code run alright. Is there anyway to test if the method is working?

Comment: Please use function_exists to check if it supported. Also check php version.

Comment: Thanks! I tried both function_exists and method_exists. The IDE says "not found", but the method is available. I think it is the IDE's problem.